# Save As/Open File Dialogs are Freezing/Using ~20% CPU

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, dialog

***This question has been asked a few times on SU, but no one ever seems to give all the information, so here we go;***

Occasionally, when using "Open a File" or "Save File" dialogs in any program on my PC, I am running into freezing errors where the entire program calling the dialog (Chrome, Photos, etc.) will freeze for upwards of 30 seconds, and is utilizing a monstrous percentage of my CPU.

**System information:**

- Intel i7-7700k at 4.2GHz
- 32 GB DDR4 at 2133 MHz
- Drives:

  - C: 120GB M.2 SSD
  - D: 1 TB Sata SSD
  - E: 4 TB Sata HDD
- Windows 10 1909 build 18363.778

**What I have tried so far:**

As asked in the comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/701543/my-notepad-is-not-responding-when-trying-to-save), I do not have any mapped drives or external drives connected to my computer. As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/735374/file-dialog-delay), I performed a clean boot, yet the issue persisted. In [this](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/programs-freezing-on-save-as-and-open-dialogs.2381705/) TH post, the user ran error checking on their drive, which fixed the issue, but Windows prompts me with:

[image]

[This post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a2505ffe-d7d1-4c7c-9443-6f3bef26e8b4/quotsave-asquot-and-quotopenquot-file-dialog-windows-very-slow-to-appear?forum=w7itpronetworking) on Microsoft Technet suggested renamed network devices could cause the problem, but no network devices are mapped on my computer. Also related is [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d45c4535-8777-4ec9-a964-44897ee71243/windows-7-slow-to-save-to-network-locations-via-quotsave-asquot-dialogs?forum=w7itpronetworking), which also references saving to network drives, which does not apply... Finally, I tried clearing the IconCache.db as suggested [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/high-cpu-usage-and-taskbar-flickering-when-i-view/f33f0d5f-2085-4622-a92d-cb8baa118bac), but to no avail.

**My thoughts:**

- The issue happens seemingly randomly, however after the initial freeze, the dialog boxes in the *same program* will not freeze for a small while (1-5 minutes).
- Rebuilding the index from control panel seems to fix my issue temporarily, but it resurfaces eventually.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and untick all NON Windows explorer extensions. In Options menu - Filter Options Hide Windows Entries then untick all that's left on Explorer tab. Does that fix it? If so reenable one by one.

Comment: @Mark is absolutely correct.. except that Microsoft can also make mistakes with things like OneDrive.. and they do A LOT.  If you exhaust the "non-microsoft" list without a culprit.. start looking at the Microsoft ones.

Answer (score 0):

External HDD's spin down between use, causing latency of perhaps 10 seconds while they spin up again. That should not happen to an internal HDD, though. Try [*Don't Sleep*](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep), for a while, to keep the drives spinning.

Also, check if an anti-malware package starts a scan on first using a drive. Keep *Task Manager* open to *Details*, let the system idle for ten or fifteen minutes, and then use an Open/Save dialog. If there is a sudden uptick of disk I/O (add those columns, if need be), or the CPU usage increases, what process is causing the drain in resources?

Comment: Also.. keep in mind that the virtual explorer shell extension stuff (like OneDrive, DropBox, Phone Storage, .. etc.. ) also get queried depending on the flags the programmer used when calling the OpenFileDialog API.  That makes this more difficult to diagnose.